# Column totals by group (Stata)

Tags: stata

Here are the relevant commands:

```
sysuse auto 
table foreign, c(max mpg max rep78) row
```

Reading through the documentation (row: add row totals), I expected it to turn out like this:

```
----------------------------------
 Car type |   max(mpg)  max(rep78)
----------+-----------------------
 Domestic |         34           5
  Foreign |         41           5
          | 
    Total |         75           10
----------------------------------
```

However, the Total row is actually just the max of the column:

```
----------------------------------
 Car type |   max(mpg)  max(rep78)
----------+-----------------------
 Domestic |         34           5
  Foreign |         41           5
          | 
    Total |         41           5
----------------------------------
```

I was wondering if there is a similar command (without me having to collapse) that would allow me to construct a table like this (within the Stata window) but actually have the Total SUM at the bottom. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Stata's answer in `table` is arguably what would be expected. Given an instruction to calculate maximums, it does that by group and for the total dataset.

You want the maximums by group, but also to see their total or sum. That seems puzzling, but it can be done indirectly:

```
. sysuse auto , clear 
(1978 Automobile Data)

. egen mpg_max = max(mpg), by(foreign) 

. egen rep_max = max(rep78), by(foreign) 

. egen tag = tag(foreign) 

. table foreign if tag, c(sum mpg_max sum rep_max)  row 

--------------------------------------
 Car type | sum(mpg_max)  sum(rep_max)
----------+---------------------------
 Domestic |           34             5
  Foreign |           41             5
          | 
    Total |           75            10
--------------------------------------
```

The trick here is that taking the maximums is done outside `table`. Then we feed just one observation in each category to `table` and the total is what is needed.